# Any convenient way to log data into the console and debug Laravel Envoy Blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-envoy

I am trying to debug Laravel Envoy Blade file with @setup configuration block.

```
@setup
// some PHP config code here...
echo('Deploy started');
@endsetup
@servers(['web' => '-q -A ' . $sshOptions . ' "' . $server . '"', 'localhost' => '127.0.0.1'])
@task('deploy:setup', ['on' => 'web'])
// some deploy commands here...
@endtask
```

I've got "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" error message in the console. This message is not enough to understand what's wrong. I suppose there is a convenient way to debug Laravel envoy blade files line by line? To log something into the console?

[image: Whoops, looks like something went wrong]

As you can see nothing returned into the console despite echo exists in the @setup block of the Blade file

As far i have found a solution, it is dirty but i can check configuration variables throwing an error with some data i want to check :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your `@setup` section you could define functions to log different types of messages by setting bash colors. Make sure to **return** PHP code that can then be executed, not echo the message itself.

```
@setup
function logSuccess($message) { return "echo '\033[32m" .$message. "\033[0m';\n"; }
function logWarn($message) { return "echo '\033[31m" .$message. "\033[0m';\n"; }
function logInfo($message) { return "echo '\033[36m" .$message. "\033[0m';\n"; }
function logLine($message) { return "echo '" .$message. "';\n"; }
@endsetup
```

In any Envoy task you could now do something like

```
{{ logSuccess('Application deployed!') }}
```

to print out `Application deployed` in green text.

If you simple want to output a message in your "standard" bash color use

```
{{ logLine('Application deployed!') }}
```

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there are more elegant solutions exist .My solution is to throw exception with the variable you want to dump right from the @setup block.

```
@setup
$var = 'test';
throw new Exception('Your var '. $var);
@endsetup
```

So you will get your debuf info, but it will be thrown and code will not be executed further.
[image]